# Change permission on other hard drive to nginx user

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I wanted to move my vhost folder outside of /var/www to my other harddrive which is available under `/media/alex/Drive` the new path should be `/media/alex/Drive/web`.

I moved to `/var/www/html` t `/media/alex/Drive/web` folder and symlinked `/var/www` to `/media/alex/Drive/web`.

When I'm running `sudo chown www-data:www-data /media/alex/Drive/web/html` the `ls -lh` command still return me as the owner of the directory. It seems like I cant change.

The `Drive` is NTFS and also used by my windows partition how I can make nginx access this folder without running it as sudo or current user.

Comment: You shouldn't create symlinks, you should change your Nginx configuration to point to the new directory. I don't know the answer to your question, but my best uninformed guess is you can't change file permissions in this way on an NTFS drive (could be wrong here). I'd probably just move it back to the old directory.

Comment: @Tim thank you for your response. You are right as it are only soft links there will be no advantage about it. The NTFS default behaviour in Ubuntu is that only the current user can access this drive so www-data can not. The following command: `sudo -u www-data stat <folder>` helped me to check that. Seems the only solution is that I allow all users to access the drive or use `ntfs-3g` and Usermapping.